# Gradient Vector of $q^Tx + t$ where $x,q \in \mathbb{R^4}, t \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I didn't learn much about "gradient vector". However, from what I understand, gradient vector is just a way to represent derivatives of multivariable functions. If that's correct, then the gradient vector of $q^Tx + t$ (where $x,q \in \mathbb{R^4}, t \in \mathbb{R}$) will not depend on $t$, and will only on $q$.

My guess is: $$\nabla f(x)  = \begin{bmatrix} q_0 \\q1\\q2\\q3 \end{bmatrix} $$

Is that correct?

Comment: You have to adhere to some convention, check out denominator vs numerator layout. Your result is correct, but things will get arbitrarily complicated in the future and you need to choose some convention to maintain consistency.

Comment: @Victor Thank you!